# Text node created in DOM not visible in browser

Tags: javascript, html, dom

i'm making a quiz and want to add checkboxes with answer choices when user clicks "Next" button. here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>quiz</title>
<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<p id="qstn">1. Which of these cities are located in South America?</p>
<form id="first_form">
</form>
<form>
    <input id="nextqstn" type="button" name="nextbutton" value="Next" onclick="changeQuestion()">
</form>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

script.js file:

```
var allQuestions = [{question: "1. Which of these cities are located in South America?", answers: 
["Montevideo", "Kyoto", "Quito", "Mexico City", "Toulouse"], correctAnswer: ["Montevideo", "Quito"]}, {question: 
"2. Which of moons of Saturn is the biggest?", answers: ["Titan", "Rhea", "Iapetus"], correctAnswer: "Titan"}, 
{question: "3. Which of these composers was considered as impressionist?", answers: ["Robert Schumann", 
"Frederic Chopin", "Maurice Ravel"], correctAnswer: "Maurice Ravel"}];
function changeQuestion(){
    var qstn = document.getElementById("qstn").innerHTML.charAt(0) - 1; 
    qstn++;
    document.getElementById("qstn").innerHTML = allQuestions[qstn].question;
    addAnswers();

    function addAnswers(){
        var numberOfAnswers = allQuestions[qstn].answers.length;
        var container = document.getElementById("first_form");
        while (container.hasChildNodes()){
            container.removeChild(container.firstChild);    
        }
        for (i = 0; i < allQuestions[qstn].answers.length; i++){
            var input = document.createElement("input");
            input.appendChild(document.createTextNode(allQuestions[qstn].answers[i]));
            input.type = "checkbox";
            input.name = "answer"
            container.appendChild(input);
            container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
        }
    }
}
```

problem is, that since "input" elements are added as they should be (checkboxes along with answers from var allQuestions (it can be seen in opera dragonfly e.g.)), browser displays only checkboxes. can someone explain why is it so? thanks

Comment: You put the script code in the wrong way, you need put it in script tag and after body close tag

Comment: The Complete js code which u have added at the end , should come in between  `<script> </script>`

Comment: thanks for editing. i didn't specified that js code is from script.js file.

Answer (score 0):

I think this happens because you are adding text nodes inside the input:

```
input.appendChild(document.createTextNode(allQuestions[qstn].answers[i]));
```

while you should be adding them after the input:

```
var textNode = document.createTextNode(allQuestions[qstn].answers[i]);
container.appendChild(input);
container.appendChild(textNode);
```

Answer (score 0):

Some points are

1. First of you need to know that any javascript code should be wrapped within a `<script></script>` block.
2. In your code you need to put the `<script src="script.js"></script>` after `</body>` tag.
3. You are doing wrong when creating a textnode i.e. you are appending it within a input element which is wrong.

Try this

```
var textNode = document.createTextNode(allQuestions[qstn].answers[i]);
container.appendChild(input);
container.appendChild(textNode);
```